# Set JSlider limits

Tags: java, swing, jslider, limits

I have a JSlider that goes from `min` to `max` values. I want to set a range limit for slider movements.

I.e. I want to put slider limits from -90 to 90, but I want to move the slider only between -45 and 60. In this case the slider does not reach limits but it's blocked before reaching it.

How can I obtain this result?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BoundedRangeModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TickSlidersSnapToTicks {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tick Slider");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JSlider slider = new JSlider(-90, 90, 0);

    // Major Tick 25 - Minor 5
    jSliderOne.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    jSliderOne.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    jSliderOne.setPaintTicks(true);

    // I want to put here slider block limits
    // ...

    frame.add(jSliderOne, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not the way a JSlider works.  Put the -45 and 60 as the minimum and maximum limits.

Comment: So I suppose I need to override something in order to obtain the result that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works (note the trick to let the slider think that the user released the mouse):

```
public class InnerSlider extends JSlider {

    int innerMin, innerMax;

    public InnerSlider(int min, int max, int innerMin, int innerMax){
        super(min,max);
        this.innerMin = innerMin;
        this.innerMax= innerMax;
        addChangeListener((e) -> {
            if(getValue() < innerMin){
                setValue(innerMin);
                getMouseListeners()[0].mouseReleased(null);
            }else if(getValue() > innerMax){
                setValue(innerMax);
                getMouseListeners()[0].mouseReleased(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quick dirty way to do this,but this violate some design principles like LSP.

```
    JSlider jSliderOne = new JSlider();

    // Major Tick 25 - Minor 5
    jSliderOne.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    jSliderOne.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    jSliderOne.setPaintTicks(true);
    jSliderOne.setModel(new DefaultBoundedRangeModel()
                    {
                      @Override
                      public void setValue(int n)
                      {
                        if (n > 50)
                        {
                          n = 50;
                        }
                        else if (n < -45)
                        {
                          n = -45;
                        }

                        super.setValue(n);
                      }
                    }
);
```

in this solution, if user tries to drag the thumb system will allow to go beyond the limit, but once user release the mouse it will set to limit.

Comment: IT works but it should be better if the thumb is blocked also during mouse dragging.